# Transloco dependency conflict

Tags: angular, dependencies, transloco

I am trying to add the Transloco package to my Angular Ionic project which I compile in VSCode. I am running Angular version 13.3.0 When I run the installation command:

```
ng add @ngneat/transloco
```

I get the following terminal errors:

[Terminal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh9Hi.png)

I've tried forcing the individual libraries to update using npm-update --force {package}, then refreshing VSCode, but that didn't resolve the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to install the package first.
I ran `npm install --legacy-peer-deps @ngneat/transloco`
and then `ng add @ngneat/transloco` and it let me continue with the library configuration process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).